# Distinct record as per Logic

Tags: sql

Consider this below table #Facebook has below data:

```
Id  Username  Friend_Username
1   U1        U2
2   U3        U4
3   U1        U5
4   U2        U1
5   U3        U4
6   B         S
7   S         B
8   S         B
9   B         S
```

Required output in using single query:

```
Id  Username  Friend_Username
1   U1        U2
2   U3        U4
3   U1        U5
6   B         S
```

or

```
Id  Username  Friend_Username
2   U3        U4
3   U1        U5
4   U2        U1
7   S         B
```

The concept behind the output is when Username of one id matches with Friend_Username of other id as well as  Friend_Username of that id matches with Username of same id the we need to consider one record and can take ane one of them:
EXMP:

```
6  B  S
7  S  B
```

In this record we should consider either `6  B  S` or `7  S  B`

Comment: Are you asking this for SQL Server or for Oracle? You tagged both. Please remove one tag. And which version (of Oracle or SQL Server) are you using?

Comment: In your input data, ID 8 and 9 are duplicates of IDs 7 and 6. Why are they not options in the output data? Or is this just an error?

Comment: You are showing result records with `Id`, `Username`, and `Friend_Username`. Is this necessary? Wouldn't it suffice to list related users, e.g. U1/U2, U3/U4, U5/U1, B/S (even when there is no record with U5/U1, but only with U1/U5)?

Comment: Hello Thorsten,why will i remove one tag.. It can be written in oracle or SQL..anything fine for me I want logic..

Comment: @Senaritra: Then why tag a DBMS at all? With the same reason you could have added tags for MS Access, Firebird, PostgreSQL, ... A query written for Oracle may not run in SQL Server and vice versa.

Comment: Please answer my other question. Are you fine with just friend pairs or do you need complete records in the results.

Comment: "*It can be written in Oracle or SQL*" doesn't make sense. Oracle uses SQL as its query language (like every other relational database). So: which database product **are** you using?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select distinct
   case when username < friend_username then username else friend_username end username,
   case when username < friend_username then friend_username else username end friend_username
from TABLE_NAME
```

Logic behind is simple: order every row, so in first column there are "smaller" values and in the second "greater". Then, it's enough to select distinct values, as this will remove any duplicate rows independently of initial order within a row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Username, Friend_Username
FROM (
   SELECT Id, Username, Friend_Username,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE 
                                          WHEN Username < Friend_Username THEN Username
                                          ELSE Friend_Username
                                       END,
                                       CASE 
                                          WHEN Friend_Username < Username THEN Username
                                          ELSE Friend_Username
                                       END
                          ORDER BY Id) AS rn
   FROM Facebook) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

**Output:**

```
Id  Username Friend_Username
----------------------------
6   B        S
1   U1       U2
3   U1       U5
2   U3       U4
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d805f/2)

**Note:** Using this technique is only necessary if you are interested in returning any field other than `Username` or `Friend_Username`. Otherwise @Michal's answer is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Username,Friend_Username
FROM tblUsers t1 
WHERE t1.Username > t1.Friend_Username
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tblUsers t2 
            WHERE t2.Username = t1.Friend_Username AND t2.Friend_Username = t1.Username
    )
```